# How to express a OR b with FormValidator::Simple?

Tags: perl, validation

```
(!$self->param{key} or $self->param{key} ~ m/^\d+$/);
```

How to convert the above to [`FormValidator::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FormValidator%3a%3aSimple) rules?

```
key => [a, b]
```

It seems `FormValidator::Simple` can only express `a AND b`,but not `a OR b`?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to allow "", "0" and a sequence of 1 or more digits optionally followed by a newline?

```
key => [ REGEX => qr/^\d*\n?\z/ ]
```

(I find `\n?\z` clearer than `$` in validation code cause most people assume you mean `\z` when you write `$`.)

Comment: So regex is the only choice to express `OR` relationship?

Comment: @new_perl, didn't say that. Most people would just make `key` optional or `REGEX => qr/^[0-9]+\z/`.

Comment: How to make `key` optional in `FormValidator::Simple`?

Comment: @new_perl, You don't use `'NOT_BLANK'` it looks like.

Comment: So blank is a special case, what if you want it to be either a `UINT` **or** `IN_ARRAY,qw/1 2/`?

Comment: @new_perl, that's not the question you asked.

Comment: @new_perl, In that case, you're just repeating yourself. I answered what I could.